# Creating N number of instances of MFC application

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc

Can someone please tell me how to go about creating a maximum of N instances of an application in MFC?

Also, if N instances are running, and one instance gets closed, then one new instance can be created (but no more than N instances can run at any one time).

Thank you in advance.
a.

Comment: Do you know how to create 1 instance? Do it N times.

Comment: Sorry- I do not understand. I want to restrict the number of instances.

Comment: Your question didn't mention restricting the number of instances. You wanted to know how to create multiple instances. Please revise the question to be more clear.

Comment: Hi Raymond- I would like to have a maximum of N instances of the app running. Fewer instances are allowed. More instances should not. If some instances are closed then new instances can be created but to a maximum number of N.

Comment: N instances per user, desktop, computer or network?

Comment: Hi Adrianm, N instances per computer. I have been trying to use the Mutex, but with little success.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a global semaphore that up to n process instances can enter. The n+1 th instance of your process will fail to enter the semaphore. Of course you should select a short timeout for the locking operation so you can present a meaningful feedback to the user.

For the semaphore stuff you can take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hwaf8fd.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use lock files. In your `CMyApp::InitInstance()` add:

```
CString Path;
// better get the path to the global app data or local user app data folder, 
// depending on if you want to allow the three instances machine-wide or per user.
// Windows' file system virtualization will make GetModuleFileName() per user:
DWORD dw = GetModuleFileName(m_hInstance, 
                Path.GetBuffer(MAX_PATH), MAX_PATH); 
Path.ReleaseBuffer();
// strip "exe" from filename and replace it with "lock"
Path = Path.Left(Path.GetLength()-3) + T("lock"); 
int i;
// better have the locking file in your class and do a clean Close on ExitInstance()!
CFile *pLockingFile = NULL; 
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) // restrict to three instances
{
    CString Counter;
    Counter.Format(T("%d"), i);
    TRY
    {
        pLockingFile = new CFile(Path + Counter, 
            CFile::modeCreate|CFile::modeWrite|CFile::shareExclusive);
        pLockingFile.Close();
        break; // got an instance slot
    }
    CATCH( CFileException, e )
    {
        // maybe do something else here, if file open fails
    }
    END_CATCH

    if (i >= 3)
        return TRUE;    // close instance, no slot available
}
```

Edit: To lock the software machine-wide, retrieve the common app folder using the following function instead of calling `GetModuleFileName()`.

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4996) // no risk, no fun
BOOL GetCommonAppDataPath(char *path)
{
    *path = '\0';

    if (SHGetSpecialFolderPath(NULL, path, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, TRUE))
    {
        strcat(path, T("\\MyApplication")); // usually found under C:\ProgramData\MyApplication
        DWORD dwFileStat = GetFileAttributes(path);
        if (dwFileStat == 0xffffffff)   // no MyApplication directory yet?
            CreateDirectory(path, NULL);    // create it

        dwFileStat = GetFileAttributes(path);   // 2nd try, just to be sure
        if (dwFileStat == 0xffffffff || !(dwFileStat & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
            return FALSE;

        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Note: This will only work from Vista on. If you have XP, writing to a global directory is an easy task, e.g. C:\Windows\Temp. I have put the function in a helper dll I only load if the OS is Vista or higher. Otherwise your software won't start because of unresolved references in system dlls.

Comment: Hi Thomiel- Thank you for your reply. I have implemented a version of what you have written. However, nothing is stopping someone to copy the executable to another directory, and then a further N instances of the executable can be run. Is there any way to lock only a maximum of N instances for the entire computer (irrespective of directories/ path and users)? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Another edit: Please have sizeof(MAX_PATH) replaced with MAX_PATH in your code!

Comment: Hi Thomiel- Thank you. In the machine wide restriction of N instances: I have tried your 2nd code, but had to modify char *path to wchar_t *path- this now compiled. However SHGetSpecialFolderPath(NULL, path, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, TRUE) returns FALSE (so GetCommonAppDataPath returns FALSE). I am using Visual Studio 2013 and Windows 7 Home Premium. Please can you help me?

Comment: No, can't do. But remember: GetLastError() is your friend! ;)